# How can I add spaces between two <input> lines using CSS?

Tags: html, css, layout

I want to control the layout with CSS. How can I regulate the spaces between `<input>` elements(I hope they are on two lines) using CSS?

```html
<form name="publish" id="publish" action="publishprocess.php" method="post">
  Title:<input type="text" id="title" name="title" size="60" maxlength="110" value="<?php echo $title ?>" <br/>
  <div>Contact<input type="text" id="contact" name="contact" size="24" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo $contact ?>" /></div><br/> Task description(You may include task description, requirements on bidders, time requirements,etc):<br/>
  <textarea name="detail" id="detail" rows="7" cols="60" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $detail ?></textarea>

  <br/><br/> price <input type="text" id="price" name="price" size="10" maxlength="20" value="<?php echo $price ?>" /><br/>
  <label> Skill or Knowledge Tags</label><br/><input class="tagvalidate" type="text" id="tag" name="tag" size="40" maxlength="60" value="<?php echo $tag ?>" />
  <br/><label>Combine multiple words into single-words, space to separate up to 3 tags<br/>(Example:photoshop quantum-physics computer-programming)</label><br/><br/> District Restriction:
  <?php echo $locationtext.$cityname; ?><br/><br/>

  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" /></form>
```

As you see, I use `<br/>` to separate  elements and get spaces, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Your labels should have the for attribute with the id of the input to be correct.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
#detail {margin-bottom:5px;}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also wrap your text in label fields, so your form will be more self-explainable semantically.

Just remember to float labels and inputs to the left and to add a specific width to them, and the containing form. Then you can add margins to both of them, to adjust the spacing between the lines (you understand, of course, that this is a pretty minimal markup that expects content to be as big as to some limit).

That way you wont have to add any more elements, just the label-input pairs, all of them wrapped in a form element.

For example:

```
<form>
<label for="txtName">Name</label>
<input id"txtName" type="text">
<label for="txtEmail">Email</label>
<input id"txtEmail" type="text">
<label for="txtAddress">Address</label>
<input id"txtAddress" type="text">
...
<input type="submit" value="Submit The Form">
</form>
```

And the css will be:

```
form{
float:left; /*to clear the floats of inner elements,usefull if you wanna add a border or background image*/
width:300px;
}
label{
float:left;
width:150px;
margin-bottom:10px; /*or whatever you want the spacing to be*/
}
input{
float:left;
width:150px;
margin-bottom:10px; /*or whatever you want the spacing to be*/
}
```

Comment: I agree, this is semantically better than my approach since the <p>:s in my example aren't really "paragraphs". It's kind of foolproof though, works in every browser and you really can't get it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

CSS:

```
form div {
  padding: x; /*default div padding in the form e.g. 5px 0 5px 0*/
  margin: y; /*default div padding in the form e.g. 5px 0 5px 0*/
}
.divForText { /*For Text line only*/
  padding: a;
  margin: b;
}
.divForLabelInput{ /*For Text and Input line */
  padding: c;
  margin: d;
}
.divForInput{ /*For Input line only*/
  padding: e;
  margin: f;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="divForText">some text</div>
<input ..... />
<div class="divForLabelInput">some label <input ... /></div>
<div class="divForInput"><input ... /></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#input {
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to minimize the use of `<br>` as much as you possibly can. HTML is supposed to carry content and structure, `<br>` is neither. A simple workaround is to wrap your input elements in `<p>` elements, like so:

```
<form name="publish" id="publish" action="publishprocess.php" method="post">

    <p><input type="text" id="title" name="title" size="60" maxlength="110" value="<?php echo $title ?>" /> - Title</p>
    <p><input type="text" id="contact" name="contact" size="24" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo $contact ?>" /> - Contact</p>

    <p>Task description (you may include task description, requirements on bidders, time requirements, etc):</p>
    <p><textarea name="detail" id="detail" rows="7" cols="60" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $detail ?></textarea></p>

    <p><input type="text" id="price" name="price" size="10" maxlength="20" value="<?php echo $price ?>" /> - Price</p>

    <p><input class="tagvalidate" type="text" id="tag" name="tag" size="40" maxlength="60" value="<?php echo $tag ?>" /> - Skill or Knowledge Tags</p>
    <p>Combine multiple words into single-words, space to separate up to 3 tags (example:photoshop quantum-physics computer-programming)</p>

    <p>District Restriction:<?php echo $locationtext.$cityname; ?></p>

    <p><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: This is an awful way of doing this. Like, abhorrent!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap everything in a DIV to achieve basic styling on inputs.

input[type="text"] {margin: 0 0 10px 0;}

will do the trick in most cases.

Semantically, one <br/> tag is okay between elements to position them. When you find yourself using multiple <br/>'s (which are semantic elements) to achieve cosmetic effects, that's a flag that you're mixing responsibilities, and you should consider getting back to basics.

Answer (score 0):

You can format them as table  !!

```css
form {
  display: table;
}
label {
  display: table-row;
}
input {
  display: table-cell;
}
p1 {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div id="header_order_form" align="center">
  <form id="order_header" method="post">
    <label>
      <p1>order_no:
        <input type="text">
      </p1>
      <p1>order_type:
        <input type="text">
      </p1>
    </label>
    </br>
    </br>
    <label>
      <p1>
        creation_date:
        <input type="text">
      </p1>
      <p1>delivery_date:
        <input type="text">
      </p1>
      <p1>billing_date:
        <input type="text">
      </p1>
    </label>
    </br>
    </br>

    <label>
      <p1>sold_to_party:
        <input type="text">
      </p1>
      <p1>sop_address:
        <input type="text">
      </p1>
    </label>
  </form>
</div>
```